# Spring Boot Integration Test Inject Controller Dependencies

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I am trying to write an integration test using Spring Boot that tests the transaction logic in one of my controllers.

What the test should do, is the following:

1. Inject one of my controllers using @Inject
2. Replace an email dependency in the controllers dependencies with a Mock, to avoid actually sending an email during the integration test.
3. Call a method of the controller
4. Assert that the transactions of the called method are properly rolled back when the mail sending mock throws an exception.

Now my problem is that, when the test runs, the controller is injected into my test class but all its dependencies are `null`. Here is my integration test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@IntegrationTest
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(App.class)
@WebIntegrationTest
public MyIntegrationTest () {

    @Inject MyController controller;

    @Before
    public void before () {
       // replace one particular dependency of controller with a mock
    }

    @Test
    public void testFoo () { ... }
}
```

Due to the test being an integration test which starts up a full spring web application context, I was expecting that my controller would have all its dependencies already autowired, but that is obviously not the case and instead all dependencies are set to null.

Question: Do I need to use some additional annotations, or setup something in my `@Before` method? Or am I approaching the problem from a completely wrong side?

**Update:** Is it possible to test my Spring MVC Layer, without testing via HTTP such as with TestRestTemplate or MockMvc? But by directly

Answer (score 0):

Test with `TestRestTemplate` instead of injecting the controller itself. Controllers is obviously a spring bean but if you directly inject it in your test class, it wont be able to initialize the context.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = ExampleStart.class)
public class ExampleTest {
    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void exampleTest() {
        String body = this.restTemplate.getForObject("/", String.class);
        assertThat(body).isEqualTo("Hello World");
    }
}
```

ExampleStart.java -> The spring boot starter class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ExampleStart extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(ExampleStart.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExampleStart.class, args);
    }
}
```

> Ref : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html

But if you want to test service method, you can use @Autowired and call the methods as usual.

Comment: If I use `@Autowire` or `@Inject` to inject a service class into my test, then the same thing happens. I get the service class injected into my test class but any dependency inside the service class that is normally injected using `@Autowire` or `@Inject` is `null`. For example I am injecting a `UserService` into my test class. The user service has a `PasswordEncoder` bean and a `UserRepository` bean, and both are `null`.

Comment: I have updated the answer, I've just tested it and it is working fine. If your actual controller method is working then the test should work. Look at what you've missed.

Comment: My `App.class` which contains the main methods is significantly simpler, it only uses `@SpringBootApplication` and has no `configure` method like you have.

Comment: Using the `TestRestTemplate` means that I have to access my controller via HTTP to test it, and I will need to parse the response to see if it contains the fields that I consider relevant. Is there no way that allows me to test my controller directly without going through HTTP?